# SQLAlchemy: how to refer to filtered fields

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am doing a relatively simple ETL project using SQLAlchemy.

There is a large existing PostgreSQL database with multiple 'schemas' (in the PostgreSQL sub-database sense), one of which is new and the project is to convert the data from schema 'old' to schema 'new'.

I have one set of two 'old' source tables that I have to join together to get the new table ... I can't see how to refer to the fields in the joined/filtered superset of the two tables. For example, if I just loop over one table:

```
allp = session.query(Permit).all()
for p in allp:
    print p.permit_id
```

... works as expected.

But if I set up a filter to combine the two tables:

```
prmp = session.query(Permit,Permit_master).filter(Permit_master.id == Permit.mast_id).all()
for p in prmp:
    print p.permit_id
```

gives

```
'result' object has no attribute 'permit_id'
```

This must be something simple, but I've tried inspecting the object with dir() to no avail.

Help please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of your query are [keyed 2-tuples](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) of `Permit` and `Permit_master`. You can access the result entities using either their position or key:

```
for p in prmp:
    print p.Permit.permit_id
    # or
    print p[0].permit_id
```